# Validate array of json objects whose size is dynamic with avro schema

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I am trying to validate array of json objects whose size is dynamic with avro schema in apache Nifi. I understand that if the size is known, we can write a schema to validate. Is there a way to validate even if the size is dynamic.

Json entry looks like the following

```
"multi_location" : [
        {
            "cityState" : "Seattle, Washington", 
            "country" : "United States", 
            "city" : "Seattle", 
            "location" : "Seattle, Washington, United States", 
            "cityCountry" : "Seattle, United States", 
            "cityStateCountry" : "Seattle, Washington, United States", 
            "state" : "Washington", 
            "mapQueryLocation" : "Seattle, Washington, United States", 
            "stateCountry" : "Washington, United States"
        }, 
        {
            "cityState" : "Toronto, Ontario", 
            "country" : "Canada", 
            "city" : "Toronto", 
            "location" : "Toronto, Ontario, Canada", 
            "cityCountry" : "Toronto, Canada", 
            "cityStateCountry" : "Toronto, Ontario, Canada", 
            "state" : "Ontario", 
            "mapQueryLocation" : "Toronto, Ontario, Canada", 
            "stateCountry" : "Ontario, Canada"
        }, 
        {
            "cityState" : "Vancouver, British Columbia", 
            "country" : "Canada", 
            "city" : "Vancouver", 
            "location" : "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada", 
            "cityCountry" : "Vancouver, Canada", 
            "cityStateCountry" : "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada", 
            "state" : "British Columbia", 
            "mapQueryLocation" : "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada", 
            "stateCountry" : "British Columbia, Canada"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the size of the array in order to validate it, as long as each object in the array has the same schema. In an Avro schema you'd just specify an [Array type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Arrays) with items that are defined by the schema of each of the individual items you list above. If some fields may not be populated for some objects in the array, you can make them "optional" by making the field a [Union](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Unions) including a "null" type as a possibility for those fields.